# How should I indicate that a status bar item is tappable?

Tags: ios, touch-screen, selection, status

My app adds an icon to the iOS status menu that shows the status of the task that my app carries out. The item goes green when the progress is running, orange when paused, and red to indicate something's gone wrong.

It also has another ability: it is able to be tapped to pause the task and tapped once more to resume the task. If tapped when it's red, it will show the error message and options going forward.

**How should I indicate that my status bar item is able to be tapped?**

<sup>This question's solution is intended to be used on iOS only — cross-platform is not important.</sup>

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? If you're truly referring to the iOS status bar (where the clock etc. is), it's a very, very small target, and users are already conditioned to the fact that items there aren't interactive (or at most, that tapping the bar would scroll to the top of the current list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely want to use icons instead of words, I think you have to add another icon before or after you service icon to make it obvious. In this case you could use the symbol for stop

[image]

And when the service is in stopped state, the icon should change to start (e g media play icon)

[image]

With this we reuse the meaning of media icons for start and stop, which I think would work for other actions as well, as long as it is the same kind of action (start/stop).